# How do I generate my tflite file from a saved Model

Tags: python, android, tensorflow

I am having below error with this command

`tflite_convert --saved_model_dir=exported_model_directory/saved_model --output_file=detect.tflite`

Error

```
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "c:\users\public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\lite.py", line 428, in convert
    "invalid shape '{1}'.".format(_get_tensor_name(tensor), shape_list))
ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'image_tensor' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'.
```

Comment: Is you problem resolved ? Else, please can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59961096/13465258) may help you.